# How to install beautiful soup on Microsoft Azure

Tags: python, azure

I am running a small project. It scrapes data from website, runs Prophet and gives results. I am making a pipeline out of it using ML Service. I tried installing packages like this:

```
run_config.environment.python.conda_dependencies = CondaDependencies.create(conda_packages=['scikit-learn','beautifulsoup4','requests','pandas'])
```

Issue is that it still doesnt recognise bs4 and gives this error:[2022-09-02 08:03:24Z]

```
Job failed, job RunId is .... Error: {"Error":{"Code":"UserError","Severity":null,"Message":"{\"NonCompliant\":\"Process '/azureml-envs/azureml_f3f7e6c5fb83d94df23933000bf02da3/bin/python' exited with code 1 and error message 'Execution failed. Process exited with status code 1. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \\\"scrapping.py\\\", line 2, in <module>\\n    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup\\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'\\n\\n'. Please check the log file 'user_logs/std_log.txt' for more details.\"}\n{\n  \"code\": \"ExecutionFailed\",\n  \"target\": \"\",\n  \"category\": \"UserError\",\n  \"error_details\": [\n    {\n      \"key\": \"exit_codes\",\n      \"value\": \"1\"\n    }\n  ]\n}","MessageFormat":null,"MessageParameters":{},"ReferenceCode":null,"DetailsUri":null,"Target":null,"Details":[],"InnerError":null,"DebugInfo":null,"AdditionalInfo":null},"Correlation":null,"Environment":null,"Location":null,"Time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00","ComponentName":null}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify where are you trying to install the above package in ML workspace OR visual studio OR databricks ?

Comment: ML workspace......in ML studio

Answer (score 0):

We need not to install the libraries into Microsoft Azure ML Studio. We need to follow the below procedure to use any of the libraries required.

Go to **azure portal** and create a **workspace**.

Create a **resource** of **Azure ML studio**

Go to **notebooks** and **create** a notebook.

In the first cell enter the below code to use beautiful soup4.Installation is not required. Just import. In this recreating the situation. One library was used to import and use.

[image]

It will be executed.

[image]

We can connect the Notebook to VS Code from azure ML studio to edit the code. For that we need to have VS code installed and all the extensions of azure must be installed including python programming.

Search for azure machine learning studio in extensions and install. Then come to ML studio and click on Edit in VS Code. Click the check box and continue.

[image]

It will open VS Code automatically and click on open.

[image]

The installation of VS Code server is going on with respect to the resource group.

[image]

Give the authentication and click on Yes

[image]

Code will be displayed in this workspace and without any errors, we can use the libraries of python programming. This workspace was created with respect to the resource group of our community workspace.

The same manner, we can try to install the libraries, which are required. The dependencies can be solved in this way. The way tried to install the dependencies from ML services using ML studio is incorrect.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about submitting pipeline to ML service?

Comment: we can directly create a pipeline with the notebook created. Follow the link to create a pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-pipeline-python-sdk

With respect to the libraries, we need not to install explicitly. We can leverage the services of Azure notebook. That is similar to jupyter notebook.